# Cant find same letters in word

Tags: c++

can somebody give some explanation how to find same letters in word?

There is the code, but its returning whole word as same letters

```
int Sting::SameLetters(string word, string sk) {
    string find; 
    find = word;    

    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        if ((find.find(tolower(word[i])) == string::npos) && 
            (sk.find(word[i]) == string::npos))
        {
            sk += word[i];
        }
    }
    return sk.length();         
}
```

So i tried to remake code and now its counting letters, but not all

```
  int letters(string word, string sk)
  {
sk = word[0];
int lenght = 0; 
for ( int i =0; i <= word.length(); i++)
{
    if(tolower(sk[0]) == tolower(word[i]))
    {
        lenght++;
    }
    sk = word[i];
}
return lenght;
   }
```

My used words for test

> ssabba ccea

Results

> ssabba(3) ccea(2)
>   I have to get ssabba(6)

Comment: For some sample strings, what is the actual and expected results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at the [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) reference. This function will search for the first occurrence in the whole string. You're iterating about all characters, so probably you just want to compare character by character to estimate the count of occurrences from a specific character? Assuming your parameter `sk` is a `std::string` with a `.length()` from exactly 1, you could do it like this:

```
size_t sameLetters(const std::string& word, const std::string& sk) {
  size_t length = 0;   
  for (size_t i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
    if(tolower(word[i]) == tolower(sk[0]))
      length++;
  }
  return length;
}
```

That would always return the number of occurrences. i.e.

```
sameLetters("Aaabc", "a");       /* returns 3 */
sameLetters("hello", "l");       /* returns 2 */
sameLetters("some string", "Z"); /* returns 0 */
```

If you tried to accomplish something different please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the logic of that `if` statement for a while.

You initialize `find` to be the same as `word`, so when you do

```
find.find(tolower(word[i])) == string::npos
```

it will indeed find the character, and the expression will be false. And because that expression is false, due to the short-circuit nature of the logical and operator `&&` the second check will not happen. This means that the `sk += word[i]` statement will never happen, and you will return the length of the unmodified `sk`.

I'm not exactly sure what you try to do, but that condition most definitely is not doing what you think it does.